# C++ Why doesn't my code print updates made to the give file

Tags: c++, macos, clang, clang++, llvm-clang

I was trying to write a code in C++ the does something like `tail -f` in linux. I found this question :
[How to read a growing text file in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757304/how-to-read-a-growing-text-file-in-c) and implemented the same. I created a `temp.txt` and started doing `echo "temp" >> temp.txt`. But my program is not printing the updates made to the file .What am I doing wrong?  This is the code I'm using

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream ifs("temp.txt");

    if (ifs.is_open())
    {
        std::string line;
        while (true)
        {
            while (std::getline(ifs, line)) std::cout << line << "\n";
            if (!ifs.eof()) break; // Ensure end of read was EOF.
            ifs.clear();
            sleep(3);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**

I've tried the same code on a linux machine and it was working fine, but it is not working on Mac. I was using `gcc` to compile the code.

`gcc -v` gives

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.49) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

**UPDATE 2**
I've investigated further and realised that I was not using gcc after all. I've installed gcc separately and it is working fine now. Is this a bug in `clang`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite possible that `cout` buffer did not flush in your tests because buffer size  did not reach the overflow limit. 
You could try flushing the buffer by either doing `std::cout << line << std::endl;` instead of `std::cout << line << "\n";` or calling `std::cout.flush()l` before `sleep(1);`. Both ways should work reliably with clang and gcc.

Answers to these questions explain buffering really well:

[C++ cout and cin buffers, and buffers in general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274057/c-cout-and-cin-buffers-and-buffers-in-general)

[Strange behaviour of std::cout in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437643/strange-behaviour-of-stdcout-in-linux)

Answer (score 1):

I have tried with your code and it is working fine.

Compiled code using following command:

```
g++ main.cpp -o testmain
```

I have open two terminal:
On one terminal first create temp.txt & run application testmain. 
and from another one run echo command and it would working fine.

[image: run application]

[image]

You want achieved this or you tried for something else...

Comment: I guess this is an issue with Mac gcc

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `ifs.sync()` after `sleep`. I was able to reproduce your problem with the code you posted, and this change solved it for me.

There is also an apparent duplicate here [clang 3.3/Xcode & libc++: std::getline does not read data after calling ifstream::clear()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19558376/clang-3-3-xcode-libc-stdgetline-does-not-read-data-after-calling-ifstream)

Answer (score 0):

The following works when appending to a file.

```
#include <iostream>                          
#include <string>                            
#include <fstream>                           
#include <unistd.h>                          

int main()                                   
{                                            
    std::ifstream ifs("temp.txt");           

    if (ifs.is_open())                       
    {                                        
        std::string line;                    
        while (true)                         
        {                                    
            while (ifs.good()) { // while we are good            
                std::getline(ifs, line); // read a line    
                if (ifs.eof()) break; // if this is the end, break       
                std::cout << line << "\n";   
            }                                
            ifs.clear(); // clear the error flags                     
            sleep(1); // sleep a bit                        
        }                                    
    }                                        

    return 0;                                
}
```

For the general case (e.g. handling file truncation etc), you could work with tellg/seekg.